# Traefik won't add prefix

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, pihole

I'm trying to set up my first homelab.
I've already got a few services running as docker-containers and also got Traefik working with them.
I now want to do the same with my PiHole instance. I've got it working so that I can access the dashboard by navigating to 'pihole.local.myurl.com/admin'. However, I would like to automatically add the '/admin' prefix.

I tried it with this docker-compose.yml, but the prefix won't be added:

```
version: "3"

# More info at https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/ and https://docs.pi-hole.net/
services:
  pihole:
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    container_name: pihole
    restart: unless-stopped
    # For DHCP it is recommended to remove these ports and instead add: network_mode: "host"
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      #- "67:67/udp" # Only required if you are using Pi-hole as your DHCP server
      #- "8000:80/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'my_password'
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole:/etc/pihole'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d'
      - './resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.rule=Host(`pihole.local.myurl.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pihole-prefix.addPrefix.prefix=/admin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.middlewares=pihole-prefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pihole-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.middlewares=pihole-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-secure.rule=Host(`pihole.local.myurl.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-secure.service=pihole"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    #cap_add:
    #  - NET_ADMIN # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)      

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Is there a mistake in my docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the location of the middleware. In this case, append `@docker` to the end of the lines for the routers where you are calling the middlewares. (Label lines 5 and 7)

Eg: Here is my compose for Organizr calling both locally defined and separate file based middlewares:

```
      - traefik.enable=true
      ## HTTP Routers
      - traefik.http.routers.organizr-rtr.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.organizr-rtr.rule=Host(`$DOMAINNAME`) || Host(`www.$DOMAINNAME`)
      ## Middlewares
      - traefik.http.routers.organizr-rtr.middlewares=organizr-redirect@docker,secure-headers@file
      ## Middlewares - Redirect to www
      - traefik.http.middlewares.organizr-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.organizr-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^http(?:s)?://$DOMAINNAME/(.*)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.organizr-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://www.$DOMAINNAME/$${1}
      ## HTTP Services
      - traefik.http.routers.organizr-rtr.service=organizr-svc
      - traefik.http.services.organizr-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=80
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
      #Attach the defined middleware to a router
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-secure.middlewares=pihole-redirectregex"
      #Define a middleware regex
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pihole-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=^https?://pihole.example.com/$$"
      #Define a replacement
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pihole-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=https://pihole.example.com/admin/"
```